# Show question ID

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, android-app

When I want to close a question as duplicate using the app, I have to enter the question ID as usual. Problem is, as far as I can tell, the question IDs are shown nowhere! Please add the ID somewhere.

Comment: You can't search for the question title?

Comment: @Undo The text field says "Question URL or ID" and there is no dynamic preview, only the button "Flag".

Comment: @Raphael You go to the question you want to mark the other question as a dupe of, click the share button, copy to clipboard, and then paste it in the dupe dialog box.

Comment: @hichris123 I only get the Android share box, no copy to clipboard possible. Maybe newer versions have that?

Comment: @Raphael I'm using Android 4.4.2, so possible. But I see a `Copy to clipboard` option in that share menu.

Answer (score 8):

The question ID is found in the URL for the question, the same way you would find it on a regular web browser. In my opinion it'd be too confusing to have "copy question id to clipboard" or something similar as a feature somewhere in the app because most the people who would find it would have no use for it.

For your scenario of sending duplicate votes you can either use the "Share" functionality to copy the question's URL to your clipboard but since it sounds like your phone for some reason does not give you that option you could also open it in a browser, copy the URL from there, then paste it into the flag dialog. The input field on that dialog accepts both inserting a regular question ID or inserting a URL.

Comment: Yea, that's a workaround but not an in-app solution. Since you are apparently involved in development, please consider that we want to *encourage* community moderation (or so SE keeps telling us). This here prevents users (and mods) from easily closing questions as duplicates, to less than 100% dedicated users won't vote for such closures when mobile. As a solution, I propose that the context menu that offers closing could also offer "copy ID/URL to clipboard" (pick the more universally useful).

Comment: @Raphael A "Copy to clipboard" function *does* exist, it's simply that your phone doesn't support the built in one for some reason. But, I would argue that the bigger issue here is the flag dialog not having the full functionality of the one on the website. I'd rather fix that than add in hacks for different android phones missing vital features.

Comment: I don't know how homogenous the Android sphere is and how stable this is over time (i.e. how much you can rely on solutions outside the app). I agree that empowering the duplicate dialogue is preferable.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi The "Copy to clipboard" share intent/option is available if you have Google Drive/Docs installed. While most devices that have Google Play, also have Google Drive installed, there is an outside chance it isn't available.