# Dupe VTC/Flag Dialog on Android

Tags: feature-request, android-app

I know the SE mobile app isn't really meant to be as feature-rich as the website, but the dialog for flagging or voting to close is just (frankly) terribly made.

For instance, when closing as a dupe, if the system has suggestions, then it shows this:

> [image]

At first glance, it's impossible to even see that there's an option to specify my own duplicate target, since the button for that is formatted in exactly the same way as the question suggestions below it.

Some sort of separation is needed here. I use the thing frequently and it still gets me every time. The formatting just makes no sense.

If the system has no suggestions, then it brings the self-specification window up right away. This is alright, and I'm more just complaining here, but I kind of wish it had a way to search for questions, like the full site. The search isn't great, but it does help me find questions I have in mind without going to Google to search for them.

---

On Android, that means exiting the app and going into another to search, or leaving the question, going to the user who has the dupe (if you know them), and then backing out into the dupe with the target link copied. It's all kind of circuitous, and I think a dupe search would help out.

---

This question is about the duplicate dialog specifically, but I want to expand the request to apply to the whole VTC/Flag dialog and system on Android, since I personally believe the whole thing could do with a rework.

This is the latest version of the SE app, as reported by Google Play (no updates available). I am on CyanogenMod 13.1 (Android 6.0.1), running on a Verizon Note 4, in case this becomes relevant.

Comment: There is a shorter way described in the answer here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281956/using-android-app-how-to-close-as-duplicate (still not so good, but better than what you do now)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I thought I mentioned that that's what I do. `leaving the question, going to the user who has the dupe (if you know them), and then backing out into the dupe with the target link copied`. I guess I should make it clearer?

Comment: You said "On Android, that means exiting the app" - no need for that, that's what I meant.

Comment: It's definitely not good but it's better than what you get in the iOS app (a simple text input to paste a URL with no suggestions)!

Comment: @Cai I also get that, but only when there are no suggestions for dupe targets.

Comment: @ShadowWizard ah, well that's why I have the `or` :p.