# Can I link to a specific question when flagging a duplicate on mobile?

Tags: support, flags, android-app, duplicate-suggestions

Recently tried to flag a question as a duplicate  from the mobile app (Android). I was presented with a list of questions to select as the duplicate, bit wasn't allowed to suggest another question. Thought maybe if I link it in a comment I could, but still no.

Is there a way in the Android app to suggest an arbitrary question as a pre-existing duplicate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't use the app, but it seems to be the first option:

> [image: Tap to manually enter a question is first option]

There is a feature request [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/284694/323179) asking for this to be changed to look less like a dupe target. That's where I got the image.

Comment: Can't believe I completely overlooked that. Checked three times before asking this question, too.